# FOSOAuthServerBundle revoke access_token

Tags: symfony, oauth

I'm trying to use fosOAuthServerBundle and fosUserBundle for my REST api.
I got the access_token and it works with my api.
But how could I revoke an access_token after using it or with a logout link?